# Differentiating between location unavailable and location not supported Android

Tags: android, gps

In my app, I am putting an icon on the action bar to warn users when the app cannot find their current location. Pressing the icon brings up a popup window telling them that I could not get their location and gives them a button to take them to settings. However, if their device does not support location at all, I would like to customize the message and not try to take them to settings.

Is there a way to programatically tell the difference between location off/unavailable and a device that does not have location capabilities?

Comment: how do you acquire location? look at the doc for that method/api/whatever. there is probably an error case specific for both situations.

Comment: Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        locationManager.getLastKnownLocation();

Answer (score 1):

The [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) class has the functionality you're looking for. The method [getAllProviders()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getAllProviders()) will return a `List` of all known location providers, including any that are not permitted to be accessed by your activity or are disabled. You can also call [getProviders(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getProviders(boolean)) to get a `List` of location providers that are currently enabled.

Comment: Would the list be empty for a device that did not support location at all?

Comment: It should be. I don't actually have a device that doesn't support location so unfortunately I can't test that out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the new Google Play Services Location API - 
`LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLocationAvailability()`

If you are using the Location Manager API -

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) // Return a boolean
locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) // Return a boolean
```